# How to add an exist term reference to a new node?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I have already add a term reference to the article, I want to create a new node by programmatically. When the new node was save, I hope the node was signed with the term data.

In the `taxonomy_vocabulary` table, I create a column named content_type. In the `taxonomy_term_data` table exist several terms with the vid of content_type. I hope when the node was created the node was tagged  by one of these terms. Can somebody help me?